# Is Sweelinck's Toccata primi toni, SwWV 286 one of the first baroque pieces?

Tags: history, classical-music

Sweelinck is considered one of the first baroque composers. In fact, most his pieces are still very Renaissance style. One of his most famous pieces that sounds more baroque is Toccata primi toni, SwWV 286. I'm wondering if this can be considered one of the first baroque pieces to ever exist.

Link to piece: https://play.spotify.com/track/2rH6diTXm9krYqShQ4XfUV

Comment: Could you pls add a link to a recording, to make it easier for people not familiar with the piece to have a listen ?  thanks

Comment: @Angst sure. I've just added it.

Comment: Fascinating questions, and I hope it gets answered someday. I suspect it requires significant analysis and then debate over whether it's characteristics weigh in favor of the Baroque or not. Anyone out there need a dissertation topic? To get started, this article -- particularly the endnotes -- might be a jumping-off point. https://www.jstor.org/stable/938876 (Bradshaw, Murray C. "The Toccatas of Jan Pieterszoon Sweelinck." Tijdschrift Van De Vereniging Voor Nederlandse Muziekgeschiedenis 25, no. 2 (1975): 38-60. Accessed July 15, 2020. doi:10.2307/938876._